# Is there any way to make this java called smaller?

Tags: java, swing, methods, refactoring

I have a class and in the class I have three methods which do the same thing but provide different inputs, So I was wondering if there is any way to make this called smaller.

My code;

```
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class test {

    public void methodclassA() {

        int result = JOptionPane
                .showOptionDialog(
                        null,
                        "How would you like you insert your data, manually or from a file? ",
                        "Inserting data", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new String[] {
                                "Manual", "From a File" },
                        JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);
        if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

            // Going to call methodA from another class
        }

        if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {

            JTextField NameField = new JTextField();
            Object[] message = { "Path location:", NameField };

            int result2 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, message,
                    "Inserting data", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new String[] { "Ok",
                            "Locate the file" }, JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);
        }
    }

    public void methodclassB() {

        int result = JOptionPane
                .showOptionDialog(
                        null,
                        "How would you like you insert your data, manually or from a file? ",
                        "Inserting data", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new String[] {
                                "Manual", "From a File" },
                        JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);
        if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

            // Going to call methodB from another class
        }

        if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {

            JTextField NameField = new JTextField();
            Object[] message = { "Path location:", NameField };

            int result2 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, message,
                    "Inserting data", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new String[] { "Ok",
                            "Locate the file" }, JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);
        }
    }

    public void methodclassC() {

        int result = JOptionPane
                .showOptionDialog(
                        null,
                        "How would you like you insert your data, manually or from a file? ",
                        "Inserting data", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new String[] {
                                "Manual", "From a File" },
                        JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);
        if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

            // Going to call methodB from another class
        }

        if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {

            JTextField NameField = new JTextField();
            Object[] message = { "Path location:", NameField };

            int result2 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, message,
                    "Inserting data", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new String[] { "Ok",
                            "Locate the file" }, JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);
        }
    }

}
```

For example, my three methods in the class are; methodclassA,methodclassB, methodclassC, all of these ask the user for the same input but however each method will call a different method from a different class.

Thanks in advance and I hope I have explained myself clearly.

edit: I forgot to mention before, I have three buttons in my main class which calls each of these three methods. for example my buttonA calls the methodclassA, buttonB calls methodclassB and buttonC calls the methodclassC.

Comment: could you please format your code first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just provide an input switch into the method so it would be something like

```
 public void methodCaller(char aSwitcher) {
      int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "How would you like you insert your data, manually or from a file? ", "Inserting data", 
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new String[] { "Manual", "From a File" }, JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);
      if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
           switch(aSwitcher)
           {
               case 'A':
                   //Going to call methodA from another class
                   break;
               case 'B':
                   //Going to call methodB from another class
                   break;
               case 'C':
                   //Going to call methodC from another class
                   break;
               default:
                   throw new IllegalArgumentExcpetion("No method defined for option" + aSwitcher);
           }


      }
      else if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
           JTextField NameField = new JTextField(); 
           Object[] message = {"Path location:", NameField};
           int result2 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, message, "Inserting data", 
                     JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new String[] { "Ok", "Locate the file" }, JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);
      }
 }
```

Possibly a better way to do it but this at least will save all the code duplication.

Then to call just make these replacements

```
methodclassA();  -> methodCaller('A');
methodclassB();  -> methodCaller('B');
methodclassC();  -> methodCaller('C');
```

Also advantage of this is that you can add 'D', 'E', 'F' and all you have to modify is to add those cases to the switch.

Comment: Hi I forgot to mention before I have three buttons in my main class which calls each of these three methods. Would that effect the behaviour of the code you provided?

Comment: Then you can create a new function like @JavaDevil made, and then call it from your three methods with the option.

Comment: @user3248466 No, see my edit as to the changes to calling the methods required.

Comment: @user3248466 the method I have outlined takes a char as an argument. This means that you will have to make sure your A is enclosed in single quotes, like in my answer. Otherwise the compiler will try and find a reference to the variable A  - which you have not defined, nor need to define.

Comment: Java Devil, everything is working fine now, your code really helped me a lot

Comment: is it possible to type in a name longer then 1 character for each case? e.g. instead of A, I want to right methodA

Comment: Also what does aSwitcher mean?

Comment: @user3248466 If you are using Java 7 you could do that to have a switch on Strings but you would have to change the argument type from `char` to `String`. `aSwitcher` is just the name I gave the variable, you can call it anything you like.

Comment: Hi, which char variable?

Answer (score 0):

I know they are all in the same class now, but depending on how they are called you could refactor and use the [Template Method Design Pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-template-method).

Comment: Hi, I am really confused now. Basically, I have three buttons in my main class. buttonA, buttonB and buttonC. buttonA calls methodA, buttonB calls methodB and buttonC call methodC. But I have no clue how I am suppose to do this with the suggestion java devil, which I like and is way easier to understand.